# Newtonsoft JSON does not contain definition for 'Any'

Tags: c#, json, umbraco

I'm trying to loop through Json object and check if all of my properties are set to `true` using `.Any()` extension

```
dynamic fares = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content.GetValue<string>("cruiseFares"));                   
foreach (var f in fares)
{
   if (fares.Any(f.fareSold != "False" ))
   {
         content.SetValue("cruiseSoldOut", soldOut);
   }
}
```

I've tried also with :

```
dynamic fares = JObject.Parse(content.GetValue<string>("cruiseFares"));
```

but then I have `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object`

Comment: What is ``content`` ?

Comment: Why not deserialize it to a list of concrete objects instead of `dynamic`? You obviously know the structure of the data.. represent it in your code with a dedicated class. That also solves your problem when you're using LINQ methods on an actual `Enumerable`..

Comment: I think it should be like this : ``JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjType>>(jsonStr);``

Comment: Sorry, that is the Umbraco content. Should have mentioned it before

Answer (score 1):

"Any" seems to be a LINQ method, which implies you to add a reference to the appropriate namespace, i.e "using System.Linq"

Another thing, there's obviously an error in your loop code above.

Would you mean something like this ?

```
if (fares.Any(f => f.fareSold != "False" ))
{
   content.SetValue("cruiseSoldOut", soldOut);
}
```

or if you can't use LINQ (it's the case with dynamic, like stated in L.B comment below), use a foreach and write the correct test :

```
foreach(var f in fares)
{
    if (f.fareSold != "False" ))
    {
       content.SetValue("cruiseSoldOut", soldOut);
    }
}
```

if it was what you meant, of course.

Or, third solution, create a proper type to deserialize in it. Your code will be safer and you will be able to use LINQ's Any method.

Comment: The namespace for the Enumerable class is System.Linq, not System.Data.

Comment: You can't use Linq with *dynamic* objects

Comment: @Dirk I've seen and corrected the mistake at the same time ? If it's you who downvoted my post, it's absolutely not a reason for...

Comment: @Richard Don't worry, I don't downvote for such a simple mistake or typo.

Comment: @L.B right ! I missed this. Th O.P could avoid "dynamic" use for this case. I've edited my post about this point.

Comment: Yes, I had the namespace in place. And I also tried to loop like you are suggesting but that gives me an error:
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
So I should avoid 'dynamic'. Any suggestions how to solve this otherwise?

Comment: @mirosz Please also read my edits. Create a type, of for something so simple you could forget LINQ and use an oldschool loop.